# Minus buttons in UITableView Edit Mode

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

When I set my UITableView to edit mode the "-" buttons appear outside the table rows. How can I get them to show up inside the rows (i.e. inside the white area).

[image: Example of Current Behavior - Minus appears outside of grouped cells.]

The behavior I'm looking for can be found in built in apps, such as on the backside of the iPhone weather app (where locations may be added and removed.)

[image: Example of Desired Behavior - iOS Weather; Minus appears in grouped cells.]
<sub>(source: [what-when-how.com](http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tmp5D87_thumb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: it by default appears outside of row

Comment: How are you dequeuing `UITableViewCell`'s to use in your table? With a standard cell style your contents should be indented to make way for the delete button, but it should appear inside the cell.

Comment: For the grouped table view style this is actually appropriate. Use the plain style if you need a different layout.

Answer (score 2):

This line will show the "-" inside the row

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}
```